# using deck screw instead of Yellow zinc construction screw？

Tags: flooring, deck, screws

Here in Canada I found the Deck Screws to be cheaper then the Yellow zinc construction screw. They are both Carbon Steel, and to my understanding, the coating on the deck screws are just more Corrosion resistance then the Yellow zinc.

So, why not/can I use deck screw everywhere? Indoor and outdoor? At least where construction screws are used?

[#8 x 3" yellow zinc](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/paulin--8-x-3-inch-flat-head-square-drive-construction-screws-in-yellow-zinc-1000pcs/1000152354)

[#8 x 3" brown deck screws](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/paulin--8-x-3-inch-deck-screws-unc-in-brown-1000-pcs-/1000152763)

[#8 x 3" yellow zinc, non-ACQ](https://www.hpaulin.com/products/screws/construction-screws/8-x-3-flat-head-socket-construction-screw-not-acq-approved-yellow-zinc-plated-unc-12786)

[#8 x 3" deck screw "duradized"](https://www.hpaulin.com/8-x-3-flat-head-socket-deck-screw-brown-duradized-ii-unc-19503)

Comment: If cost really matters you might want to check your costs at a fastener store if you buy in bulk.

Comment: I mean, leaving cost aside, is there a reason not wise doing so?

Comment: I'm not a carpenter so looking up screw uses is laborious for me.  My instinct would be that the deck screw exceeds the common screw, but there may be specifics to their use that I'm unaware of.  The "Not ACQ approved" on the yellow zinc screws means that they are not to be used in ACQ chemical pressure treated lumber.  Consumer construction parts have fairly large and random markups based on volume sold or lack thereof.  You have to buy in extremely large quantities to find the true prices of things.  Copper is expensive, but it can be cheaper sometimes to buy a much larger size of wire.

Comment: Incidentally your hyperlinks are horrible.  Could you fix them so the URL is not visible at least, and actually we don't like important information in hyperlinks, so it would be better if you transferred the relevant information to the question.  You can make [a neater hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121422/use-hyperlink-in-comment) by putting square brackets around the words you want to be the link and following immediately with round brackets around the hyperlink.  You can also highlight text and use the hyperlink tool.

Comment: You're right, @KH, the formatting was bad, but it's easy to fix and makes a nice example for a new poster.

Comment: The question isn't particularly clear. Are you asking about structural ratings? If so, you need to explain the situation. If not, there are no rules.

Answer (score 1):

Stainless steel is corrosion resistant ; the various paints and coatings are not  ( in spite of creative names ). In my location , any deckcrew that is not stainless, rusts to useless in about 15 years . Rust rate depends on how much time they are damp. And, even with proper clearance and pilot holes ,the coatings are degraded when driven in

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms, deck screws are equal to yellow construction screws.

However, there's variance among different manufacturers. So you'll find crappy yellow screws and crappy deck screws, just as you'll find good ones.

The only other thing is aesthetics. In some cases, a painted head isn't a good look. (Hinges jump out as an example.)

Answer (score 0):

Coated deck screws have a different head: it's less square and needs a tapered square bit.

This means you need a deck screw bit, but you could use a normal screw head too if only fastening a few.

These screws also have more friction at the shaft & thread. You need more torque to insert, but the head/bit interface is capable of less torque due to the taper, and it will maybe strip or cam-out sooner.

This means that for a larger project your materials cost is somewhat offset by more labour time and frustration. On net it may not be a big deal, especially with the correct driver bit.

If you find there's a price difference, compare with elsewhere to see if the coated screws are under-priced (good for you) or if the normal screws are over-priced (and so buy elsewhere). Quantities matter too.

Comment: @SteveSether, OP's have square heads. And yes, what you wrote confirms it all offsets the lower price OP found for the coated screws.

Comment: for some reason, they are both square where I live

Comment: @jjrfadpammtpiagkjq square is fine, it's most common. Because of the coating, the square is slightly tapered, and you can get a special bit for that. But as I wrote, it's not necessary.